# I would like to read data from an output file and create stacked bar graphs?

Tags: r, dynamic, graph, bar-chart

This is the code that I have used because I am new in R and I kind of used something I found online to create graphs, however I hard coded majority of it and now I just want it to read the information from the file and create these graphs. The code I have now is as such:

```
        ylabels <-  c( "sampleXYZ",
        "sampleXY",
        "sampleG",
        "sampleF",
        "sampleE",
        "sampleD",
        "sampleC",
        "sampleB",
        "sampleA"
        )

       tablex = read.table(file="testGraphData.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\t")
       dataframe <- as.data.frame.matrix(tablex)

       test <- matrix(c(dataframe[1,2],dataframe[2,2],dataframe[3,2],dataframe[4,2],dataframe[5,2],dataframe[6,2],dataframe[7,2],dataframe[8,2],dataframe[9,2],5,10,20,25,30,35,40,45,50), 
              nrow =2 , 
           ncol=9, 
           byrow=TRUE,
           dimnames = list(c("Calculated", "Normal"),
                           ylabels))


       par(mar=c(5.1, max(4.1,max(nchar(ylabels))/1.8) ,4.1 ,2.1))

       plot_colors <- c("#458B74","#8B0000")
       barplot(test,
               col = plot_colors,
               las=2,
               beside = TRUE,
               legend = T,
               args.legend = list(x="topright", cex=.75),
               xlim = c(0,110),
               horiz=T)

       abline (v=seq(0,80, 20))
```

This is the graph and this:
[image]

This is the graph I want but, I want to create it directly from the output file which is tab delimited and looks like this (has NO headers):

```
   sampleA  7
   sampleB  0
   sampleC  53
   sampleD  0
   sampleE  28
   sampleF  0
   sampleG  0
   sampleXY 0
   sampleXYZ    12
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work

```
table=read.table(file="testGraphData.txt")
names=table[,1]
values=table[,2]
barplot(values, names=names)
```

or

```
table=read.table(file="testGraphData.txt")
barplot(table[,2], names=table[,1])
```

Comment: I also want to plot the normal values as well any ideas how I could add that piece? Thanks for your immediate response.